# Python shebang line

Tags: 16.04, python, shebang

I am trying to execute a script in python as a cgi script using apache2. However instead of executing, the file gets downloaded. I have allowed my python file to be an executable. I think this is happening because my shebang line is incorrect. So how do I know what is the correct shebang line to add. I have Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.5.2 installed. Any help/direction would be of great great help. Thanks

**EDIT**

Adding the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
query = form.getvalue('query')
print("Content-type:text/html")
print()
print("<html>")
print("<head>")
print("<title>search results</title>") 
print("</head>")
print("<body>")
print("\
<div style = 'position:absolute;text-align:center;width:100%;left:0%;top:0%;margin:0%;padding:0%;'>\
<h4 style = 'font-family:Arial;font-size:24px;color:dodgerblue;'>muGoogle</h4>\
<form class='form-wrapper' action='hello.py' method='get'>\
    <input type='text' id='search' placeholder='Search docs related to...' required name = 'query' style = 'font-family:Arial;font-\size:14px;width:60%;height:40px;'/>\
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit' style = 'height:40px'>")
print("<p> search results for: %s </p>" % query)
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding the html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>muGoogle</title>
<link type = 'stylesheet' ref = 'style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div style = 'position:absolute;text-align:center;width:100%;left:0%;top:15%;margin:0%;padding:0%;'>
<h4 style = 'font-family:Arial;font-size:48px;color:dodgerblue;'>muGoogle</h4>
<form class='form-wrapper' action='query.py' method='get'>
    <input type='text' id='search' placeholder='Search docs related to...' required name = 'query' style = 'font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;width:60%;height:40px;'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit' style = 'height:40px'>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3**

adding the default config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all 
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ 
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: @Zanna Done. please check

Comment: If the file gets downloaded, then the Apache CGI module isn't enabled, or not configured correctly

Comment: @muru By enabling apache cgi module you mean the ScriptAlias line and the following block, right? I have added that in my config file, still cant seem to get it work

Comment: no, for that block to be of any use, a module has to be loaded by Apache. It seems you're looking for the plain CGI module, try `sudo a2enmod cgi`

Comment: Just FYI: you mention having Python 3 installed, but are executing the file with Python 2. Change your shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file gets downloaded instead of being run by Apache, then the module needed for running it is hasn't been loaded by Apache. For Python, there are a few modules that can be used. It seems the one used here is the simple CGI module, so do:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```